# Adobe software does not save to network share

Tags: virtualbox, file-sharing

I'm running Windows 7 inside virtualbox on a linux host. I have shared my linux filesystem so it's accesible in Windows under \vboxsvr\sharename. I've mounted this share on S:.

For most software, it works fine. Adobe software like Photoshop has problems with it though. I can read from S: just fine, but if I try to save something it gives me the message "There are no more files". How can I make it able to write to the share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known Issue Adobe is working on it.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2903926